# Create a View Controller Template so that I can use it through out the my iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview

I want to create a template view controller which includes these things:

1. A navigation bar which is throughout the app
2. A header which is used throughout the app
3. A standard background (the background of the view controller should be same throughout the app)
4. A footer which is used throughout the app

The bottom line is I need a custom view controller class which has a navigation bar, a header, a footer and a background. I will then replace the all view classes to this class in the interface builder.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, you would create a custom view controller as a subclass of UIViewController. You may want to do the same with UITableViewController. Lets assume you name them myViewController and myTableViewController.

Your interface builder views would then refer to this classes or their sub classes respectively.

**BackgroundColor:** 
However, the view controllers to not have a background color them selfs. Their view does have a background color and the view controller may set its view's background color with some constant value. Make sure that all views in the view hierarchy who's background color should be the same as the general background do not have a background color themselfs. (or the clear color respectively: `[UIColor clearColor]` )

You can then set the color in your view controller like this:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5];
```

Bare in mind that there are smarter ways of coding this rather than having the values hard coded at many places in the code.

**NavigationBar:** 
The navigation bar is a property of the navigation controller. Usually there is only one navigation controller in the app (unless it is a tab bar based app, then there may be more). Therefore there is no need for subclassing all view controllers just to aim for a common custom navigation bar.

**Header and Footer:**
Frankly I am not sure what you mean by that. You may refer to table view headers and footers. If so then, als already mentioned, an application wide superclass "myTableViewController" may be your choice, which provides common headers and footers along the app.

Answer (score 0):

The navigationBar is part of the `UINavigationController` which your viewControllers will be added to so this will automatically be standard across them.

As for creating the custom view controller, you are essentially asking "How do I do inheritance" which is outside the scope of a single answer. There are plenty of good tutorials out there if you do a google search.